# iOS Custom Font, Adding Font Family

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts

I hope this Q is not a duplicate, i'ved looked for a week now for an answer with no success.

I've Successfully added several custom fonts named:

DINOT-Bold.otf, DINOT-Black.otf, DINOT-Medium.otf, DINOT-Reg.otf and DINOT.otf.

All added to the .plist as needed.
But when trying to access them via:

```
self.dynamicLabel1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"DINOT-Light" size:20.0f];
self.dynamicLabel2.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"DINOT-Medium" size:27.0f];
```

It's not working. I know that sometimes one need to "put" the "other" name of the font.
Mine is: DIN OT. Like so:

```
self.dynamicLabel1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"DIN OT" size:20.0f];
```

The Problem is, all of the files "other name" i've added above is called DIN OT, so now, XCode cant "tell" the difference (which is Bold/Med etc.)

Help Please, what can i do?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you google it, you will find reports of OTF fonts not working correctly on iOS. I don't know why this can happen, since OTF should be supported, but it seems to happen. Maybe it depends on the fonts internals (like in your case the fact that all the faces share the same name).

One possible path forward would be converting the font to TTF, using [fontforge](http://fontforge.org) or other tools. Another possibility, would be fixing your OTF fonts so that its different faces so not share the same internal name.

Comment: Thanks :) Will look into it!
Converting OTF to TTF is my last option, it is said one can lose quality by doing so.

Comment: If you are aiming at high quality typography, conversion will surely leave out something. But this would be more a concern when using high-dpi (e.g., 2540dpi or 5080dpi) professional printing devices, IMO.